# What does WebM DocType Version Signify?

Tags: ffmpeg, webm, matroska

If a WebM's `DocTypeVersion` is 4, what does that signify and correlate to?  Is that [version 4 of the Matroska specification draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-cellar-matroska-04)?  Or does WebM have its own versioning independent of Matroska?  I couldn't find any information on [webmproject.org](https://www.webmproject.org/)

After analyzing a WebM file created by `ffmpeg`, I see the "Document Type Version" is 4:

```
$ ffmpeg -i audio.opus -a:c copy audio.webm
$ mkvinfo audio.webm

+ EBML head
|+ EBML version: 1
|+ EBML read version: 1
|+ Maximum EBML ID length: 4
|+ Maximum EBML size length: 8
|+ Document type: webm
|+ Document type version: 4             <=  This is what I'm referencing
|+ Document type read version: 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebMs is a type of EBML document.

From https://github.com/cellar-wg/ebml-specification/blob/master/specification.markdown

> The version of the EBML Body is found in EBMLDocTypeVersion. A parser
>   for the particular DocType format can read the EBML Document if it can
>   read either the EBMLDocTypeVersion version of that format or a version
>   equal or higher than the one found in EBMLDocTypeReadVersion.

FFmpeg will set version to 4 for WebM if there's an audio stream with codec Opus or if video stream has an alpha channel stored in an additional block or is a stereo video.

Answer (score 1):

The [WebM Container Guidelines](https://www.webmproject.org/docs/container/#demuxer-and-muxer-guidelines) strongly imply that these versions are the same as the Matroska verion numbers in their note on `DocReadTypeVersion`:

> - `DocReadTypeVersion` SHOULD follow the Matroska specification.
>
>   - Example: Files with v2 elements should have a `DocReadTypeVersion` of 2.

As far as the meaning of and differences between `DocTypeVersion` and related `DocTypeReadVersion`, [section 21 of version 4 of the draft Matroska Specifications](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-cellar-matroska-04.html#name-matroska-versioning) has a good explanation.

> `DocTypeVersion` MUST be equal to or greater than the highest Matroska version number of any `Element` present in the Matroska file. For example, a file using the `SimpleBlock Element` MUST have a `DocTypeVersion` equal to or greater than 2. A file containing `CueRelativePosition Element`s MUST have a `DocTypeVersion` equal to or greater than 4.
>
> The `DocTypeReadVersion` MUST contain the minimum version number that a reading application can minimally support in order to play the file back -- optionally with a reduced feature set. For example, if a file contains only `Element`s of version 2 or lower except for `CueRelativePosition` (which is a version 4 Matroska `Element`), then `DocTypeReadVersion` SHOULD still be set to 2 and not 4 because evaluating `CueRelativePosition` is not necessary for standard playback -- it makes seeking more precise if used.

To add to that, `SimpleBlock Element`s are version 2 `Elements` that contain actual video or audio data, which is why the `DocTypeReadVersion` should be 2 if they are used - they have the actual file content! So a player that doesn't support version 2 wouldn't be able to play back the content in those `Elements`.